# Load Twitter page from my Android app

Tags: android, twitter

I have my android app and I would like next: -When somebody press the button on my application it will load the Twitter application with my twitter page. 
So people can see my twitter page and leave some questions.
For example :
1) User_1 open my Android application and press the button "Contact with us"
2) My application load Twitter app if it installed
3) Twitter app sign in automatically using User_1 account and load my page.
So I don't know how to make Intent with data about my twitter page and load it using deffault User_1 account.
Answers with example would be much appreciated.

Comment: if you want them to just browse to your twitter page and you have twitter installed you just need to edit the URL such that it directs to your page. go to your own profile in a browser and copy your URL

Comment: can you show some example ?...becouse I dont understand where I can put URL

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.twitter);

    WebView mWebView;
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView1);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.twitter.com/#!/editextentionhere");
}
```